# 'int' has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup

I'm supposed to enter the url of a website that lists numerous names. Then "Find the link at position 18 (the first name is 1). Follow that link. Repeat this process 7 times. The answer is the last name that you retrieve.
Hint: The first character of the name of the last page that you will load is: C"
I'm always getting an error that 'int object has no attribute get'.
Here's my code so far:
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

```
# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('a')
try:
    input("please enter a number between 0 and 129: ")
except:
    print("Invalid input")
x=list(range(0,129))
for tag in range(len(x)):
    print(tag.get('href', None))
```

How can I overcome this error?

Comment: What input is this failing for?

Answer (score 2):

Well, your range/len/list/range loop is total nonsense.  You clearly need to be iterating through the tags you received, and you aren't even storing the number you read.

```
# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('a')
try:
    tagno = int(input("please enter a number between 0 and 129: "))
except:
    print("Invalid input")
for n,tag in enumerate(tags):
    if n+1 == tagno:
        print(tag.get('href', None))
        break
```

As an explanation of why you got the error you did, let's look at your code:

```
x=list(range(0,129))
```

That means x is [0,1,2,3,4,...,127,128], with a length of 129.  Next:

```
for tag in range(len(x)):
```

This will produce exactly the same sequence as the one you stored in `x`.  So, `tag` will be 0, then 1, then 2, etc.

```
    print(tag.get('href',None))
```

So here, `tag` is an integer.  That's why you got the error.

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong. How can I expand this to do the following: Find the link at position 18 (the first name is 1). Follow that link. Repeat this process 7 times. The answer is the last name that you retrieve. Hint: The first character of the name of the last page that you will load is: C" Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: This code doesn't get tags above 100. If I enter, let's say 102, then it will not return anything. Is it the code or the data? As explained above, I need to work from link 18 and then enter the link 7 times.